# How to get the number of processes running?

Tags: c#, process

How to return the number of processes running?

I intend to use that value in a label that is updated every second using a timer, so I can keep an eye over the number of processes running on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a .NET program you would call [Process.GetProcesses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get that. It returns an array, so just count the number of elements and you have the number of processes running.

Comment: So i should use: `Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();`? but how do i count the number of elements? thanks

Comment: Please try something. Asking for all the details is not going to teach you much. I'm sure you can find out how to get the number of elements in an array.

Comment: Done, thanks for helping: ´Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
                int size = processlist.Length;
                label.Text = size.ToString();´

Answer (score -1):

You can also do that:

```
For Each a As Process In p
    pName = a.MainWindowTitle.ToString
    pName = pName.Substring(0, pName.Length - 6)
    File.WriteLine("Word Process Name : {0} is started on time {1}", pName, a.StartTime)
    fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(a.MainWindowTitle)
    File.WriteLine("Path Of the file is  : {0}", fullPath)
Next
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. It isn't a good idea to resurface an old question just to provide an answer that doesn't answer it.

Comment: But this could be the answer of people are looking for dear